# Не могу добавить пост на сайт, при добавлении выходит из учетной записи

Tags: python, html, django, form, model

Почему не работает форма, при вводе данных выходит с учетной записи

views.py

```
class AddPage(PermissionRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, DataMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = AddPostForm
    template_name = 'women/addpage.html'
    title_page = 'Добавление статьи'
    permission_required = 'women.add_women'  # <приложение>.<действие>_<таблица>

    def form_valid(self, form):
        w = form.save(commit=False)
        w.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class AddPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cat = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), empty_label="Категория не выбрана", label="Категории")
    husband = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Husband.objects.all(), empty_label="Не замужем", required=False, label="Муж")

    class Meta:
        model = Women
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'content', 'photo', 'is_published', 'cat', 'husband', 'tags']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 50, 'rows': 5}),
        }
        labels = {'slug': 'URL'}

    def clean_title(self):
        title = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if len(title) > 50:
            raise ValidationError("Длина превышает 50 символов")

        return title
```

models.py

```
class Women(models.Model):
    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        DRAFT = 0, 'Черновик'
        PUBLISHED = 1, 'Опубликовано'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Заголовок")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name="Slug",                           validators=[
                               MinLengthValidator(5, message="Минимум 5 символов"),
                               MaxLengthValidator(100, message="Максимум 100 символов"),
                           ])
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", default=None,
                              blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Фото")
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Текст статьи")
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Время создания")
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Время изменения")
    is_published = models.BooleanField(choices=tuple(map(lambda x: (bool(x[0]), x[1]), Status.choices)),
                                       default=Status.DRAFT, verbose_name="Статус")
    cat = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='posts', verbose_name="Категории")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('TagPost', blank=True, related_name='tags', verbose_name="Теги")
    husband = models.OneToOneField('Husband', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   null=True, blank=True, related_name='wuman', verbose_name="Муж")
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='posts', null=True, default=None)


    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Известные женщины"
        verbose_name_plural = "Известные женщины"
        ordering = ['-time_create']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['-time_create'])
        ]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', kwargs={'post_slug': self.slug})
```

html code

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-error">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
    {% for f in form %}
    <p><label class="form-label" for="{{ f.id_for_label }}">{{ f.label }}</label>{{ f }}</p>
    <div class="form-error">{{ f.errors }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><button type="submit">Отправить</button></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.